# regex 3 alphanumeric or 1 asterisk

Tags: java, regex

can someone please help me with a regex to match a group that either contains 3 alphanumeric characters or 1 asterisk character?

any of `01A` `A12` `a12` `01a` etc or `*` i need to extract the 3 alphanumeric or * whichever is present.

i tried

```
([\\w]{3}|[\\*])
([\\w]{3})|([\\*])
```

and few others. nothing worked.

thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: This is a pretty simple regex, and with a little reading, I'm sure you could figure it out.

Comment: i tried ([\w]{3}|[*]{1}), ([\w]{3})|([*]{1}) and few others. nothing worked.

Comment: @user2327272 Put that in the body of the question.

Comment: You don't have to surround `\\w` or `\\*` with `[` `]` brackets. Also how ware you using your patterns because they seem to work fine for me. `"123".matches("([\\w]{3})|([\\*])")` -> `true`.

Comment: Finally,

    ".*([\\w]{3}|[\\*]).*"

works,

i am using pattern, matcher and group java classes/methods.
i couldn't answer my question.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I wish you'd have tried first, but this is a simple one. We can match alphanumeric characters by saying `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, or we can match an asterisk by escaping it `\*`. We use the pipe to match one of several alternatives `(A|B|CDE)`, and we can put a number in braces to match more than one of something `A{2}`. So, that should help you find the answer. If you try to put it together on your own, we'll help you along if you have any issues.

Comment: We can also match alphanumeric characters with `\p{Alnun}`.

Comment: Yeah Jash, I had second thoughts when I saw the comments above. I hope it wasn't appropriate to post it as an answer since it technically isn't one, anymore.

Comment: One thing to note: boundaries. Either there should be whitespace on both sides or nothing. Also `\w` would be the wrong choice (as it won't match around `*`. That complicates things a little because I think `(<=^|\s)` and `(?=$|\s)` are fairly non-obvious. The core regex itself is trivial, of course, but it's the conditions around it that can make it reliable or not that are often hard to write, especially for beginners.

Comment: i tried ([\w]{3}|[\*]{1}), ([\w]{3})|([\*]{1}) and few others. nothing worked.